# Catch error in combined pipe of pipeable rxjs operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular5

We've just upgraded one of our applications to Angular 5, and started to transition into [lettable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md) as introduced in rxjs v5.5.

Because of this, we have rewritten our observable pipelines to the new syntax with the `.pipe()` operator.

Our previous code would look like this, with a `.catch()` inside the `.switchMap()` as to not interrupt the running of effects if an error is thrown.

```
@Effect()
loadData$ = this.actions$
.ofType(LOAD_DATA)
.map((action: LoadData) => action.payload)
.withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getCultureCode))
.switchMap(([payload, cultureCode]) => this.dataService.loadData(payload, cultureCode)
  .map(result => {
    if (!result) {
      return new LoadDataFailed('Could not fetch data!');
    } else {
      return new LoadDataSuccessful(result);
    }
  })
  .catch((err, caught) => {
    return Observable.empty();
  });
  );
```

In the case of an error thrown in the call to the `dataService` it would be caught and handled (simplified the error handling here).

With the new syntax and use of `.pipe()`, we now have this

```
@Effect()
loadData$ = this.actions$
.ofType(LOAD_DATA)
.pipe(
  map((action: LoadData) => action.payload),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getCultureCode)),
  switchMap(([payload, cultureCode]) => this.dataService.loadData(payload, cultureCode)),
  map(result => {
    if (!result) {
      return new LoadDataFailed('Could not fetch data!');
    } else {
      return new LoadDataSuccessful(result);
    }
  })
  );
```

How can I in a similar fashion catch any thrown errors in the observable pipeline, using the new syntax?

Comment: After refactoring you moved `map` out of `switchMap` projection, so any error will close the outer stream. Something like: `switchMap(([payload, cultureCode]) => this.dataService.loadData(payload, cultureCode).pipe(map..., catch...))` should do the job.

Comment: Works great @arturgrzesiak! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

After refactoring you moved `map` out of `switchMap` projection, so any error will close the outer stream. To keep both streams equivalent, you need to use `pipe` in the projection itself like that:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

// ...

@Effect()
loadData$ = this.actions$
.ofType(LOAD_DATA)
.pipe(
  map((action: LoadData) => action.payload),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getCultureCode)),
  switchMap(([payload, cultureCode]) =>
    this.dataService.loadData(payload, cultureCode)
      .pipe(
         map(result => {
           if (!result) {
             return new LoadDataFailed('Could not fetch data!');
           } else {
             return new LoadDataSuccessful(result);
           }
          }),
         catchError((err, caught) => {
           return EMPTY;
         })
      )
  )
);
```

Comment: This works exactly as I intended, though `catch` has been renamed to `catchError`! Thanks!

Comment: I had to do: `import { empty } from 'rxjs;` and then `empty()` in rjxs v6

Comment: FYI, empty() has been deprecated in favor of EMPTY constant: import {EMPTY} from "rxjs/internal/observable/empty"

Comment: @jk. not sure about it - could you paste a link to a release note? I am on `6.3.3` and there is `empty`. Moreover importing directly from `rxjs/internal` seems bit weird to me.

Comment: @artur grzesiak Link to what I saw: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/empty.ts  It does seem weird, but it was the only one not deprecated in intellij. I'm at rxjs-compat@6.3.2 and rxjs@6.2.0.Not sure if I need both of those or not..

Comment: ... and what if "this.store.select(getCultureCode)" the other source were to error?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it that way.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Effect()
loadData$ = this.actions$
.ofType(LOAD_DATA)
.pipe(
  map((action: LoadData) => action.payload),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getCultureCode)),
  switchMap(([payload, cultureCode]) =>
    this.dataService.loadData(payload, cultureCode)
      .pipe(
         map(result => {
           if (!result) {
             return new LoadDataFailed('Could not fetch data!');
           } else {
             return new LoadDataSuccessful(result);
           }
          }),
         catchError(err => of('error', err))
      )
  )
);
```